# GoblinXNA: exception while changing screen resolution

Tags: c#, xna

I'm facing a problem in my GoblinXNA program which is the screen resolution, if im using 480*640 everything is fine and my application is working perfectly

```
captureDevice.InitVideoCapture(0, FrameRate._60Hz, Resolution._640x480,
                ImageFormat.R8G8B8_24, false);
```

but if i change that to 800x600 or 1280x1024 like this:

```
captureDevice.InitVideoCapture(0, FrameRate._60Hz, Resolution._800x600, ImageFormat.R8G8B8_24, false);
```

i get an exception

```
GoblinXNA.GoblinException was unhandled
  Message=Could not start video stream
Could not setup graph
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
  Source=GoblinXNA
  StackTrace:
       at GoblinXNA.Device.Capture.DirectShowCapture.StartupVideo(UCOMIMoniker mon) in C:\GoblinXNAv4.0\src\Device\Capture\DirectShowCapture.cs:line 576
       at GoblinXNA.Device.Capture.DirectShowCapture.InitVideoCapture(Int32 videoDeviceID, FrameRate framerate, Resolution resolution, ImageFormat format, Boolean grayscale) in C:\GoblinXNAv4.0\src\Device\Capture\DirectShowCapture.cs:line 276
       at Se.HInitialize(Scene scene) in C:\Se\H.cs:line 119
       at Se.App.Initialize() in C:\Se\App.cs:line 96
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at Se.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Se\Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException:
```

any idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by Changing the resolution in DirectShowCapture.cs to 1280x720 and recompile the GoblinXNA.dll